If $A$ and $B$ are normal with $\sigma(A),\sigma(B)\subseteq \mathbb{R}\cup\mathbb{T}$, does $\text{rank}(AB-BA)=\text{rank}(A^*B-BA^*)$?
I already asked this question for general $B$ and it was answered negatively here, so if the statement is true, one has to use the assumption on $B$ as well.
In the original question I already discussed possibilities for tackling this problem. In short, one can write $A$ (and $B$) as either the sum $A_1+A_2$ or the product $A_1 A_2$ of a self-adjoint matrix $A_1$ and a unitary matrix $A_2$ with $A_1A_2=A_2A_1$.
Moreover, one can assume that one of the matrices is diagonal, while the other is diagonalizable with a unitary matrix which is not the identity, because if $A=UDU^* $ and $B=VEV^* $, then $$\begin{split}\text{rank}(AB-BA) &=\text{rank}(UDU^* VEV^* -VEV^* UDU^* )\\
&=\text{rank}(DU^* VEV^* U-U^* VEV^* UD)\\
&=\text{rank}(D(U^* V)E(U^* V)^*-(U^* V)E(U^* V)^* D)\end{split}$$ and $U^* V$ is just another unitary matrix.

Here is a counterexample (with links to WolframAlpha for computations):
$$A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & N  \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) \; \mbox{ and } \; B = \left( \begin{array}{cc} N & 0 \\ 0 & 1  \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $$
where $N = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 & 1  \\ 1 & 0 & 1  \end{array}  \right)$. $N$ is normal with spectrum $\{2, (1 - i \sqrt{3})/2, (1 + i \sqrt{3})/2\} \in \mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{T}$, hence $A$ and $B$ are normal both with spectrum $\{1, 2, (1 - i \sqrt{3})/2, (1 + i \sqrt{3})/2\} \in \mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{T}$.
Since $A$ has real coefficients, $A^* = A^T$.
On the one hand, $[A,B]$ has rank $2$. On the other hand, $[A^T, B]$ has full rank $4$. QED
Interestingly, in a positive direction, from the fact that $\mathrm{rank}(C) = \mathrm{rank}(C^*)$ for any $C$, it is not difficult to show that if $A$ and $B$ are normal with one them (say $B$) either hermitian, skew-hermitian or (slightly harder to prove) unitary, then we do have $\mathrm{rank}([A,B]) = \mathrm{rank}([A^*,B])$.

Thank you very much! I didn't believe, someone would find a counterexample. How did you come up with this?

@mathemagician99 As it frequently occurs in math: by groping in the dark and by luck! First, I had no intuition as to why your conjecture could hold, despite the positive direction I mentioned. I went on the Wikipedia page about 'normal matrices' in the hope that some nontrivial examples would be given, and the matrix $N$ was mentioned. After some experimentations, I noticed that it would be probably better to look for counterexamples where $A$ and $B$ are at least $4\times 4$ and having 'mutually interacting blocks'... Of course, I'd like to better understand the reason for the failure too...

I tried using NumPy to find a conterexample, but it only gave me false alarms due to rounding errors. I used the "simplification" where one of the matrices can be diagonal but ironically this seemed to make it harder to find counterexamples because in this case, the diagonal of the commutators is always zero.
